# Giving a Y-Scale to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two axes. I want to plot `4e-6` in `ax1` and plot `4e-7` in `ax2`. How can I make y-axis of `ax1` like y-axis of `ax2`? i.e, it should be scaled to `1e-6` and the scale should appear at the top of the y-axis.

Here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 3)
y1 = np.full_like(x, 4e-6)
y2 = np.full_like(x, 4e-7)

ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

Here is the figure:

[image]

Comment: Update matplotlib to version 3.4.3. I can't reproduce your issue. Both y-axis show with the offset.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved as shown here: [default_tick_formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/scalarformatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-scalarformatter-py)

Mentioning the y_axis value as `4*1e-7` instead of `4e-7`, will result in the solution to your requirement.

The following was recreated and the solution is produced below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 3)
y1 = np.full_like(x, 4*1e-6)
y2 = np.full_like(x, 4*1e-7)

ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

The results would look[image: result]

Comment: Please see this problem as a general problem, not for this specific issue. How can I change the Y-scale to be like the right one? Thanks